# Parse Migration MongoDB - objectId must be a string ObjectIdHex

Tags: mongodb, parsing, migration, mlab

Hi all I was looking to migrate data from an old parse instance to a new one. I did a data export from Parse and then imported the data into mLab. I am able to see all the data correctly but when I try to login a user hitting the new data base I get the error of...

objectId must be a string: ObjectIdHex('asdfadsfas')

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Rename the objectId field in your json file into _id and then import it. It worked for me.